# Image won't be resized in javascript when removing alerts

Tags: javascript

I have a database with image paths. through PHP, I insert the pictures on my website. The problem is that the code that I have won't work. So, I decided to put some alerts to figure out what is the issue. After going through the alerts, I noticed that the images were resized and repositioned. After some reading, I found out that this is because the javascript is executed in the same time as the HTML and CSS and the alert halts the javascript, letting the HTML and CSS to be executed. How should I change my code to make the images work? This is the code in question:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName("produs");
    var pic = document.getElementsByClassName("imagine_produs");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < pic.length; i++) {
        alert(pic[i].width);
        if ( pic[i].width > 200 ) {
            pic[i].width="200";
            alert(pic[i].width);
        }
        var marg = (box[i].clientWidth - pic[i].clientWidth ) / 2;
        pic[i].style.marginLeft = marg + "px";
        pic[i].style.marginRight = marg + "px";
    }
```

*Also, I have made a photo album that is in order to show how the code executes:*

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
*What other way is there to either halt the code or to rearrange it so that it works like in the last picture?*

THanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use

```
console.log()
```

instead of alert() for debugging purposes. That way you can monitor what your code is doing without interrupting it with prompts.

Apart from that, the funtionality of your code might better be realised with CSS eventually (i.e. margin:auto; img max-width:90%; …).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your tip. Also, would you thinks it is a good practice to use window.onload for this type of functions?

Comment: Depending on when and where you include your JS this can be a good way to prevent the code from being executed before everything is loaded that the code actually affects (in this case: images)

Comment: i am including it after the body, so last in the file. I suppose i am correctly using window.onload than. THanks